# Can I repair Windows 8.1 boot from Ubuntu? (did not install Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, 18.04, windows-8, boot-repair

My ASUS X551CA-SX024H laptop recently came across the following problem:

while I was using it, in my W8.1 OS, it suddenly froze. I waited for like 20 minutes, and since nothing happened I pressed the power off button. When I turned it on again, it could just go to the UEFI screen, since there was nothing besides the DVD where I could boot the computer from. At this point I guessed something was wrong with the HDD.

After around 3 days of rest I tried to turn the computer on again. After loading for some time, a blue recovery screen was showing for like 0.1s, then the computer was automatically resetting and showing that screen again, looping all the time. I left it looping, and after some time voilà, it was "ready to operate", meaning that my OS booted and I could access it. The computer took extremely long time to do easy tasks such as opening task manager. After some hours it stopped working again.

Now my computer does never boot the OS. However, the recovery screen shows up for a decent time now. It says my computer needs to be repaired, my boot files are wrong, and it tells me the specific error 0xc000014c (well-known \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD error, as I could see in the internet).

All the possible solutions suggest to get the W8.1 installation in an USB drive and repair the system booting from such an USB. So, that is what I tried. The problem comes here. I can boot from the USB correctly, as the Windows blue symbol shows up, and after that the loading dots appear. After that, the screen goes (lighted) black and nothing happens. Even left the computer "loading" this screen overnight and still nothing happened. Summarizing, I can't boot Windows and I can't boot Windows recovery tools.

I have to add that after the second time the computer crashed, the Windows Boot Manager is always showing up in my PC booting menu, whilst the first time it crashed this Boot Manager was somehow broken.

So I have little options now. I managed to get a 18.04 Ubuntu running on my computer, and I was wondering if I can repair my Windows 8.1 boot using it.

Thanks.

EDIT: Ubuntu shows the message "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON"

Comment: *"Ubuntu shows the message "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON"* - I think that is you main issue here, probably also why Windows failed in the first place. I'd not  hesitate to backup all important data and replace the drive. Ubuntu can do a lot but it can not repair a failing hardware, unfortunately but you can use it for data recovery if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will say the same things:
Backup your data ASAP...

I have repaired a lot of Windows Installation using Disk-Repair boot in USB key available in Sourceforge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/).
But the only time I had the information "DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON", well the disk die soon after...

Just in case the repair succeed, don't forget to do a scandisk to check your disk cluster...